# Separating data from multiple runs for a subject and writing to correct output files

Tags: python

I am trying to break a large data file which contains behavioural data from an experiment with around 40 runs on average (varies across subjects), into textfiles corresponding to run-number with the results of that run. 
The data look like this:

Subject, run, "Sample", result1, result2, reaction time, feedback

now, run number 1 may have about 10 trials, and run no 2 may have 16 and so on.

I have perused stackoverflow enough to learn how to open multiple output files corresponding to the list of runs, but my code yields unhelpful results (as in all data as opposed to just what I need) when I try to allocate all the values from "Result1" corresponding to the trials of "a" run to its output file (so, all Result1 values for Run 1 should end up in Run1.txt).

This is my code:

```
    infile = open("Subject25.txt", 'r')
    gamelist = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30,31, 34]

for i in gamelist:
   with open("Subject25.txt", 'r') as input:
      with open('samples%i.txt' %i, 'w') as output:
         for aline in input:
             values = aline.split()
             output.write('{:10}{:10}\n'.format(values[3]))
```

I have tried using conditionals to see if I could pick out result1 values but I am not sure I did it correctly. I am learning python *on the job* and would be grateful for useful advice on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how big your file is, but it isn't too big something like this would probably work, using a dictionary to split the data into their respective runs:

```
data = {}
with open("Subject25.txt", 'r') as input:
    for aline in input:
        values = aline.split()
        if values[3] not in data.keys():
            data[values[3]] = aline + "\n"
        else:
            data[values[3]] += aline + "\n"
for key, values in data.iteritems():
    with open('%s.txt'%key, 'w') as output:
        output.write(values)
```

Your code is failing because it doesn't do anything to verify that the line belongs in the file. It should work if you add something like

```
if values[3] == value_for_file:
    output.write('{:10}{:10}\n'.format(values[3]))
```

The disadvantage of doing that is that you are reading the input file 40x times.

Comment: Hiya @wils484,thanks for the suggestions and for taking the time!. The first option did not yield what I was looking for. As for using a conditional to see whether a datapoint belongs in the file,  if you see my code example above, I indicate runs in a "gamelist"...so gamelist is Values[1] when I split and read the lines of the input file. What I am trying to do is to pick up all the Result1 values for a given run and assign it to a file named after the run. I am still encountering the same problem. Could you please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Hi All,
                 With help from a friend I figured out why I was striking out with my earlier bit of code. As @wils484 pointed out, a conditional would have solved the problem (and I tried it even before posting on here, but in vain) but the key to getting it to work was realising that values[1] came out a string and needed to be converted to an integer before it could be used to loop through;
so the bit of code that helped solve the problem is:

```
    if int(values[1]) == i:
       output.write(values[3]+ " ")
```

So that resolved my issue and the code spewed separate files with the pertinent data.